# How to write conditional window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I have following javascript line for redirection of webpage.

```
 window.location.href ="<?php echo $this->url->link('product/category', 
'path=' . $data['category_id']);?>_"+child_select;
```

`child_select` is a javascript variable. I want to display `_child_select` i.e.undescore and whatever child_select value only if it present.

and I have to do it in same statement without repeating the code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Conditional/Ternary operator `? :`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to check if the `child_select` is present. If not use the URL without `_` and `child_select`.

Set the value of Base path in a variable. If the `child_select` is present append it with `_` to the base path.

```
var path = "<?php echo $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $data['category_id']);?>";

window.location.href = child_select ? path + '_' + child_select : path;
//                                  {  If present then append   }
```

The above statement is equivalent to

```
if (child_select) {
    window.location.href = "<?php echo $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $data['category_id']);?>_" + child_select;
} else {
    window.location.href = "<?php echo $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $data['category_id']);?>";
}
```

Comment: I made some changes, in your answer, and it worked for me,

`window.location.href = (child_select && child_select.length >= 1) ? prod_path + '_' + child_select : prod_path;`

Answer (score 1):

Then you can check `child_select` undefined:

```
if (typeof child_select != 'undefined')
{
   window.location.href ="<?php echo $this->url->link('product/category', 
'path=' . $data['category_id']);?>_"+child_select;
} else {
   window.location.href ="<?php echo $this->url->link('product/category', 
'path=' . $data['category_id']);?>";
}
```